# Loading Dynamic Augmented Matrix from file in C

Tags: c, matrix

For a homework assignment, I must read an augmented matrix from a file, then perform Gaussian Elimination with partial pivoting. The problem is that we're required to load any size Matrix (square or not) that is augmented with the vector b.

Ax = b is the equation, obviously, and we are given a file containing [A b]. An example of the file is as follows:

> 2.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000  1.0000000000000000e+000  4.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000  1.0000000000000000e+000
>
> 1.0000000000000000e+000  3.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000 -3.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000
>
> 4.0000000000000000e+000  0.0000000000000000e+000  0.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000  3.0000000000000000e+000  3.0000000000000000e+000
>
> -2.0000000000000000e+000  1.0000000000000000e+000  1.0000000000000000e+000  0.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000  2.0000000000000000e+000
>
> 3.0000000000000000e+000  8.0000000000000000e+000  4.0000000000000000e+000 -7.0000000000000000e+000  8.0000000000000000e+000  1.0000000000000000e+000

In this file, there are 6 doubles per line, so it's a 5x5 Matrix with the vector b augmented with it.

Since I'm not allowed to use command line arguments for the size (other argument is the file), I'm curious to know how I should go about loading the doubles into a Matrix. Each test file has a different number of lines, for example one has 3 lines, and the other has 10.

The matrix will be stored as a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` function to read the numbers separated by a space and count the number of tokens to know the dimensions of your matrix.

`strtok` is a function that performs *string tokenising*.

See c-faq for an example on how to use `strtok`:

http://c-faq.com/lib/strtok.html

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for but couldn't find it.